# How to access selected data inside template in django?

Tags: django

I want to display selected user name.

template

```html
<select class="form-control" name="user_id">
  {% for user in user_list %}
    <option value="{{ user.id }}">{{ user.id }}</option>
  {% endfor %}         
</select>
<div>
  "I want to display name of selected user here"
</div>
```

views.py

```
class UsersView(TemplateView):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["user_list"] = [
           {"id": "0", name: "A"},
           {"id": "1", name: "B"},
           {"id": "2", name: "C"},
        ]
        return context
    template_name = "users.html"
```

How Can I access selected data in template?

Comment: send your view file code

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I added views.py code.
Do you need any other information ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using pure js,

1) Give your dropdown an `id` & add a `onchange` event

```
<select class="form-control" name="user_id" id="my_dropdown" onchange="updateUser()">
  {% for user in user_list %}
    <option value="{{ user.id }}">{{ user.id }}</option>
  {% endfor %}         
</select>
```

2) Put `"I want to display name of selected user here"` inside `div` or `span`

```
<span id="selected_user"> "I want to display name of selected user here" </span>
```

3) Create the func which you used in onchange, which'll put the selected value of dropdown into the `span` which we created above.

```
function updateUser() {
  document.getElementById("selected_user").innerHTML = document.getElementById("my_dropdown").value;  
}
```

I hope this was clear to you, if not let me know.

Comment: It's clear !
I guess from your answer that Django doesn't support some dynamic template syntax to access html event. Javascript does.